# Create a distorted checker texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

So how could I make a checker texture distorted like most other blender textures in the material nodes category?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well the only inputs that can affect distortion on the Checker texture is the Vector input and the Scale input. You can plug the colour output of any other texture node into either of these 2 inputs to distort the checkered effect quite dramatically.

**Solution 1**

[image]

**Solution 2** - Distortion created by mixing Texture Coord and Noise texture with more subtle effect.

[image]

*Please note the Subtract node is optional and is used if the texture doesn't reach the edge of the object. It is used to offset the texture so that it fills all surfaces of the object.*

Credit for this technique goes to Bartek Skorupa in his [Manipulate texture coordinates like a boss](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAUmLcXhUj0) presentation.

Comment: Ok. I was really wondering if the lines between color one and color two can be distorted on the checker texture? Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Sure, you just need to turn down the distortion amount a lot so that it's close to the original check texture but a little wavier. Depends on how much noise frequency you want along the lines. Can you post a sketch to show the pattern you want?

Comment: I was hoping for something like this: [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C93DFC2A43845EA8!629&authkey=!ABZAPzV4OvKQBrE&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng) I threw a checker texture into Photoshop, but I was really hoping this could be made in blender itself...

Comment: Okay, I've added a second solution that approximates your example.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't think that was actually possible! I noticed it also works with a distorted wave texture...